# Is Forcecage unaffected by Antimagic Field?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, antimagic-field

A Forcecage could be made of walls of force:

> an immobile, invisible cubical prison composed of either bars of force or solid walls of force (your choice).

And considering that Antimagic field description says:

> Certain spells, such as wall of force, prismatic sphere, and prismatic wall, remain unaffected by antimagic field

Does that mean that a Forcecage remains unaffected by Antimagic Field?

And the space inside the Forcecage is impervious to Antimagic field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### An existing [*forcecage*](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/spellsFtoG.html#forcecage) spell's effect is *probably* unaffected by an incoming [*antimagic field*](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/spellsAtoB.html#antimagic-field) spell's effect

A spell that creates multiple walls of force—like the the 4th-level Sor/Wiz spell *force chest* [evoc] (*Spell Compendium* 97) or the 7th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*forcecage*](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/spellsFtoG.html#forcecage) [evoc] (*PH* 233)—requires using the rules for the 5th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*wall of force*](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/spellsTtoZ.html#wall-of-force) [evoc] (*PH* 298-9), and those include how the *wall of force* spell's effect interacts with the effect of the 6th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*antimagic field*](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/spellsAtoB.html#antimagic-field) [abjur] (*PH* 200), this despite the *antimagic field* spell's description specifying only the spell *wall of force*.

The spell *forcecage* says

> Like a *wall of force* spell, a *forcecage* resists [*dispel magic*](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/spellsDtoE.html#dispel-magic), but it is vulnerable to a [*disintegrate*](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/spellsDtoE.html#disintegrate) spell, and it can be destroyed by a [*sphere of annihilation*](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/magicItemsICA.html#sphere-of-annihilation) or a [*rod of cancellation*](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/magicItemsPRR.html#rod-of-cancellation).

Compare that with the spell *wall of force*, which says that it's effect

> is unaffected by most spells, including *dispel magic*. However, *disintegrate* immediately destroys it, as does a *rod of cancellation*, a *sphere of annihilation*, or a *Mordenkainen’s [disjunction](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/spellsMtoO.html#mages-disjunction)* spell.

The reader *must* refer to the spell *wall of force* to learn more about the spell *forcecage* (otherwise, for example, the phrase "vulnerable to a *disintegrate* spell" is meaningless). And, if trying to determine how, for example, the *antimagic field* spell's effect interacts with the *force cage* spell's effect, the reader'll end up back at the spell *wall of force* anyway.

It would take an *extremely* strict reading of the spell *antimagic field*—followed by a personal definition of what a *forcecage* spell's effect's now-mysterious walls of force were *actually* made of—to have an existing *forcecage* spell's effect suppressed by an *antimagic field* spell's effect.

#### Walls of force usually block line of effect but an *antimagic field* spell's effect does not

Normally, the *antimagic field* spell's effect just doesn't care about a magical effect that would block its line of effect: the *antimagic field* spell's effect causes the existing magical effect to be suppressed. But, like the spell *antimagic field* says—and the *Rules Compendium* confirms—, "A *wall of force*… isn’t affected by antimagic" (11).

Thus even an existing *forcecage* spell's *barred* cage effect allows spells to be cast while those within would be, if uncaged, in an *antimagic field* spell's effect, although usually not beyond the barred cage effect's walls. While an "otherwise solid barrier with a hole of at least 1 square foot through it does not block a spell’s line of effect" (*PH* 176), the *forcecage* spell's barred cage effect has only "half-inch wide [bars] with half-inch gaps between them."

However, casting the spell *forcecage* while within an existing *antimagic field* spell's effect *and* picking as the *forcecage* spell's effect's point of origin a crosshairs within the *antimagic field* spell's effect means the *forcecage* spell's effect is suppressed while the *antimagic field* spell's effect remains. (However, picking for the *forcecage* spell's effect's point of origin a crosshairs that's *outside* the *antimagic field* spell's effect seems to mean the *forcecage* spell's effect functions normally. The *antimagic field* spell's effect doesn't block line of effect (*RC* 11)—an apparent reversal of how the spell *antimagic field* functioned according to the *Dungeons and Dragons, Third Edition* FAQ—, but opinions on exactly how this works vary widely.)

Comment: So... [this OOTS comic](http://www.giantitp.com/comics/oots0627.html) relies on DM fiat?

Comment: @Roflo It actually relies on the "*extremely* strict reading" that I mentioned. Also, if I remember correctly, while based on *3.5*, *Order of the Stick*'s  author's said he often uses — let's say — *interesting* spell interpretations to further the plots (cf. this infamous [strip](http://www.giantitp.com/comics/oots0448.html)).

Answer (score 0):

## Yes, it is unaffected

> An antimagic field suppresses any spell or magical effect used within, brought into, or cast into the area, but does not dispel it.

Further more:

> Like a wall of force spell, a forcecage resists dispel magic, but it is vulnerable to a disintegrate spell, and it can be destroyed by a sphere of annihilation or a rod of cancellation.

Unless it is not one of the mentioned, it is unaffected.